# How to find closest locations for a list of locations in more efficient way?

Tags: python, r, latitude-longitude

Looking for the help with an algorithm for local machine or cluster (Python, R, JavaScript, any languages).

I have a list of locations with coordinates.

```
# R script
n <- 10
set.seed(1)
index <- paste0("id_",c(1:n))
lat <- runif(n, 32.0, 41)
lon <- runif(n, 84, 112)*(-1)
values <- as.integer(runif(n, 50, 100))
df <- data.frame(index, lat, lon, values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df) <- c('loc_id','lat','lon', 'value')

   loc_id      lat        lon value
1    id_1 34.38958  -89.76729    96
2    id_2 35.34912  -88.94359    60
3    id_3 37.15568 -103.23664    82
4    id_4 40.17387  -94.75490    56
5    id_5 33.81514 -105.55556    63
6    id_6 40.08551  -97.93558    69
7    id_7 40.50208 -104.09332    50
8    id_8 37.94718 -111.77337    69
9    id_9 37.66203  -94.64099    93
10  id_10 32.55608 -105.76847    67
```

I need to find 3 closets locations for each location in the table.

This is my code in R:

```
# R script
require(dplyr)
require(geosphere)

start.time <- Sys.time()
d1 <- df
sample <- 999999999999
distances <- list("init1" = sample, "init2" = sample, "init3" = sample)
d1$distances <- apply(d1, 1, function(x){distances})

n_rows = nrow(d1)
for (i in 1:(n_rows-1)) {
  # current location
  dot1 <- c(d1$lon[i], d1$lat[i])
  for (k in (i+1):n_rows) {
    # next location
    dot2 <- c(d1$lon[k], d1$lat[k])
    # distance between locations
    meters_between <- as.integer(distm(dot1, dot2, fun = distHaversine))

    # updating current location distances
    distances <- d1$distances[[i]]
    distances[d1$loc_id[k]] <- meters_between
    d1$distances[[i]] <- distances[order(unlist(distances), decreasing=FALSE)][1:3]

    # updating next location distances
    distances <- d1$distances[[k]]
    distances[d1$loc_id[i]] <- meters_between
    d1$distances[[k]] <- distances[order(unlist(distances), decreasing=FALSE)][1:3]
  }
}
```

But it takes too much time:

```
# [1] "For 10 rows and 45 iterations takes 0.124729156494141 sec. Average sec 0.00277175903320313 per row."
# [1] "For 100 rows and 4950 iterations takes 2.54944682121277 sec. Average sec 0.000515039761861165 per row."
# [1] "For 200 rows and 19900 iterations takes 10.1178169250488 sec. Average sec 0.000508433011308986 per row."
# [1] "For 500 rows and 124750 iterations takes 73.7151870727539 sec. Average sec 0.000590903303188408 per row."
```

I did the same in Python:

```
# Python script
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

n = 10
np.random.seed(1)
data_m = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 5)
data = {'loc_id':range(1, n+1), 
        'lat':np.random.uniform(32, 41, n),
        'lon':np.random.uniform(84, 112, n)*(-1),
        'values':np.random.randint(50, 100, n)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)[['loc_id', 'lat', 'lon', 'values']]
df['loc_id'] = df['loc_id'].apply(lambda x: 'id_{0}'.format(x))
df = df.reset_index().drop('index', axis = 1).set_index('loc_id')

from geopy.distance import distance
from datetime import datetime 

start_time = datetime.now() 

sample = 999999999999
df['distances'] = np.nan
df['distances'] = df['distances'].apply(lambda x: [{'init1': sample}, {'init2': sample}, {'init3': sample}])

n_rows = len(df)

rows_done = 0
for i, row_i in df.head(n_rows-1).iterrows():
    dot1 = (row_i['lat'], row_i['lon'])
    rows_done = rows_done + 1
    for k, row_k in df.tail(n_rows-rows_done).iterrows():
        dot2 = (row_k['lat'], row_k['lon'])
        meters_between = int(distance(dot1,dot2).meters)
        distances = df.at[i, 'distances']
        distances.append({k: meters_between})
        distances_sorted = sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[next(iter(x))])[:3]  
        df.at[i, 'distances'] = distances_sorted
        distances = df.at[k, 'distances']
        distances.append({i: meters_between})
        distances_sorted = sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[next(iter(x))])[:3]
        df.at[k, 'distances'] = distances_sorted

print df
```

Almost the same performance.

Anybody knows if there is a better approach? In my task it has to be done for 90000 locations. Even thought about Hadoop/MpRc/Spark, but have no idea how to do in distributed mode.

I am glad to hear any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: It seems like some kind of k-nearest neighbour algorithm should be able to do this fast, although I don't know enough about latitude/longitude to know exactly how to specify the right distance measure, or which `knn` implementations would calculate it.

Answer (score 4):

If Euclidean distance is ok then `nn2` uses kd-trees and C code so it should be fast:

```
library(RANN)
nn2(df[2:3], k = 4)
```

This took a total of 0.06 to 0.11 seconds on my not particularly fast laptop to process n = 10,000 rows and a total of 1.00 to 1.25 seconds for 90,000 rows.

Comment: I am really impressed... Never heard of this library. The calculation is approximate,   but I believe I can calculate 6 neatest, recalculate the Haversine formula for them, sort and remain first 3 location. Thank you G. Grothendieck. I will update my post soon with your solution.

Comment: Check out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/how-do-i-convert-the-distance-between-two-lat-long-points-into-feet-meters

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a `python` solution with `scipy`

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from geopy.distance import vincenty
v=distance.cdist(df[['lat','lon']].values,df[['lat','lon']].values,lambda u, v: vincenty(u, v).kilometers)
np.sort(v,axis=1)[:,1:4]
Out[1033]: 
array([[384.09948155, 468.15944729, 545.41393271],
   [270.07677993, 397.21974571, 659.96238603],
   [384.09948155, 397.21974571, 619.616239  ],
   [203.07302273, 483.54687912, 741.21396029],
   [203.07302273, 444.49156394, 659.96238603],
   [437.31308598, 468.15944729, 494.91879983],
   [494.91879983, 695.91437812, 697.27399161],
   [270.07677993, 444.49156394, 483.54687912],
   [530.54946479, 626.29467739, 695.91437812],
   [437.31308598, 545.41393271, 697.27399161]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Clean code and 8 times better performance. The sample of 1000 rows was done for 60 seconds instead of 500 seconds.

Comment: 1000 rows - 499500 iterations (1 min)
90000 rows - 4049955000 iterations (8108 min).
so sad...
I believe I have to cluster the dataset. And run calculation in parallel inside each cluster.

Comment: @IldarGabdrakhmanov try dig out with numpy , as far as I know it should be even faster than scipy

Comment: You don't necessarily need the full vincenty calculation, you can use a simplified euclidean without the `sqrt` : `(q1 - p1)^2 + (q2 - p2)^2` because you're just doing a comparison to then find the 3 nearest. Once you have the 3 nearest you can then use a more formal distance formula.

Comment: Just realized. With `scipy` I will get only distances, but not the location itself. I mean I can get `[384.09948155, 468.15944729, 545.41393271]`, but I will not know what exact location is located in 384km from `id_1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve this problem with C++ and my library
[GeographicLib](https://geographicslib.io) (version 1.47 or later).  This uses true *ellipsoidal* geodesic
distances and a
[vantage point tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree)
to optimize the search for nearest neighbors.

```
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <GeographicLib/NearestNeighbor.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;

// A structure to hold a geographic coordinate.
struct pos {
  string id;
  double lat, lon;
  pos(const string& _id = "", double _lat = 0, double _lon = 0) :
    id(_id), lat(_lat), lon(_lon) {}
};

// A class to compute the distance between 2 positions.
class DistanceCalculator {
private:
  Geodesic _geod;
public:
  explicit DistanceCalculator(const Geodesic& geod) : _geod(geod) {}
  double operator() (const pos& a, const pos& b) const {
    double d;
    _geod.Inverse(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon, d);
    if ( !(d >= 0) )
      // Catch illegal positions which result in d = NaN
      throw GeographicErr("distance doesn't satisfy d >= 0");
    return d;
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    // Read in pts
    vector<pos> pts;
    string id;
    double lat, lon;
    {
      ifstream is("pts.txt");   // lines of "id lat lon"
      if (!is.good())
        throw GeographicErr("pts.txt not readable");
      while (is >> id >> lon >> lat)
        pts.push_back(pos(id, lat, lon));
      if (pts.size() == 0)
        throw GeographicErr("need at least one location");
    }

    // Define a distance function object
    DistanceCalculator distance(Geodesic::WGS84());

    // Create NearestNeighbor object
    NearestNeighbor<double, pos, DistanceCalculator>
      ptsset(pts, distance);

    vector<int> ind;
    int n = 3;                  // Find 3 nearest neighbors
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i) {
      ptsset.Search(pts, distance, pts[i], ind,
                    n, numeric_limits<double>::max(),
                    // exclude the point itself
                    0.0);
      if (ind.size() != n)
          throw GeographicErr("unexpected number of results");
      cout << pts[i].id;
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < ind.size(); ++j)
        cout << " " << pts[ind[j]].id;
      cout << "\n";
    }
    int setupcost, numsearches, searchcost, mincost, maxcost;
    double mean, sd;
    ptsset.Statistics(setupcost, numsearches, searchcost,
                      mincost, maxcost, mean, sd);
    long long
      totcost = setupcost + searchcost,
      exhaustivecost = ((pts.size() - 1) * pts.size())/2;
    cerr
      << "Number of distance calculations = " << totcost << "\n"
      << "With an exhaustive search = " << exhaustivecost << "\n"
      << "Ratio = " << double(totcost) / exhaustivecost << "\n"
      << "Efficiency improvement = "
      << 100 * (1 - double(totcost) / exhaustivecost) << "%\n";

  }
  catch (const exception& e) {
    cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This reads in a set of points (in the form "id lat lon") for pts.txt,
puts them in a VP tree.  Then for each point it looks up the 3 nearest
neighbors and prints the id and the id's of the neighbors (ranked by
distance).

Compile this with, e.g.,

```
g++ -O3 -o nearest nearest.cpp -lGeographic
```

If pts.txt contains 90000 points, then the computation completes in
about 6 secs (or 70 μs per point) on my home computer after doing about 3380000 distance
calculations.  This
is about 1200 times more efficient than a brute force calculaion
(doing all *N*(*N* − 1)/2 distance calculations).

You could speed this up (by a factor of a "few") by using a crude
approximation to the distance (e.g., spherical or euclidean); just
modify the DistanceCalculator class appropriately.  For example, this
version of DistanceCalculator returns the spherical distance in
degrees:

```
// A class to compute the spherical distance between 2 positions.
class DistanceCalculator {
public:
  explicit DistanceCalculator(const Geodesic& /*geod*/) {}
  double operator() (const pos& a, const pos& b) const {
    double sphia, cphia, sphib, cphib, somgab, comgab;
    Math::sincosd(a.lat, sphia, cphia);
    Math::sincosd(b.lat, sphib, cphib);
    Math::sincosd(Math::AngDiff(a.lon, b.lon), somgab, comgab);
    return Math::atan2d(Math::hypot(cphia * sphib - sphia * cphib * comgab,
                                    cphib * somgab),
                        sphia * sphib + cphia * cphib * comgab);
  }
};
```

But now you have the added burden of ensuring that the approximation
is good enough.  I recommend just using the correct geodesic distance
in the first place.

Details of the implementation of VP trees in GeographicLib are given
[here](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/nearest.html).